# Differentiating an Exponential Generating Function

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, derivatives

In the notes on the Euler-Maclaurin Formula, I'm having difficulty verifying the conjecture on the notion that $B_n(x) = nB_{n-1}(x)$. My initial approach to verifying the conjecture stated in $(1.0.1)$ can be seen within $Lemma \, (2.)$

Bernoulli Polynomials denoted by $B_n(x)$ for nonnegative integers $n$ is defined in $(0.)$

$(0.)$
$$  \frac{ze^{zx}}{e^{z}-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{}B_n(x)\frac{z^{n}}{n!}$$

$Conjecture \, (1.0.1)$: Differentiating with respect to $x$ one obtains the following relation in $(2)$

$(2.)$
$$B_n(x)=nB_{n-1}(x).$$

$Lemma \, (2.)$: In an attempt to verify the conjecture stated in $(1.0.1)$ I performed the following operations on the Generating Function $B_n(x)$ as follows:
$$\frac{ze^{zx}}{e^{z}-1}=\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}B_n(x)\frac{z^{n}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}\frac{d}{dx}B_n(x)\frac{z^{n}}{n!}$$

Initially in summary from my failure in $Lemma(2)$, i'm having trouble differentiating a Exponential Generating Function: what would be a viable approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{ze^{zx}}{e^z_1}\right)&=z\left(\frac{ze^{zx}}{e^z_1}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n(x)\frac{z^{n+1}}{n!}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty B_{n-1}(x)\frac{z^n}{(n-1)!}\tag 1\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_{n}'(x)\frac{z^n}{n!}\tag 2
\end{align}$$

Equating coefficients of the series in $(1)$ and $(2)$ reveals$B_0'(x)=0$ and

$$B_n'(x)=nB_{n-1}(x)$$

for $n\ge 1$.